# ydn.db - cannot get() value from IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

using `ydn.db-isw-core-e-qry-dev-raw.js` from http://dev.yathit.com/index/downloads.html

when I do the following, my console will display the expected output

```
var db = new ydn.db.Storage('storage');
var id = 1234;
db.put('store-name', {foo: 'bar'}, id);
db.get('store-name', id).done(function(record) {
    console.log("record", record);
});
```

`record Object {foo: "bar"}`

however, if I omit the `put()` my console returns undefined

```
var db = new ydn.db.Storage('storage');
var id = 1234;
db.get('store-name', id).done(function(record) {
    console.log("record", record);
});
```

`record undefined`

if I use Chrome's Developer Tools, I can see the record in my Resources/IndexedDB

why would the record not be retrieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>It seems like `-raw` format is only work with full repo and run build process, `ant deps`Try using development build `-dev`.</del>

As it turn out, you are using auto-schema. At the time of `db.get` run, database is not connected, so you have to wait connection is ready as follow:

```
var db = new ydn.db.Storage('storage');
db.onReady(function() {
    var id = 1234;
    db.get('store-name', id).done(function(record) {
        console.log("record before", record);
    });
    db.put('store-name', {foo: 'bar'}, id);
    db.get('store-name', id).done(function(record) {
        console.log("record after", record);
    });
})
```